# Printing only the duplicates from an int array and how many times they occur

Tags: java

I am trying to print only the duplicate elements from an array and how many times each of them appear.

**Example:**

```
Number 0 appears 3 times; 
Number 12 appears 2 times; 
Number 43 appears 2 times
```

My code prints all the elements of the array rather than printing only duplicate elements.

I must mention that i cannot use `HashMap`, only `conditional statments`.
 Thanks
Below is the **code :**

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87 };
    int counter = 0, temp = 0;// variable that holds the temporary value of each element
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        temp = array[i];
        counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (temp == array[j]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number:" + array[i] + "occurs :" + counter + " times");
    }
```

Comment: use Hashmap and increment key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting repeated elements in an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array)

Comment: Don't complicatee, I'll post answer below in a second.

Comment: i forgot to mention, this is an assignment for my teacher, i am not allowed to use Hashmap, only conditional statements, thanks anyway

Comment: This question is duplicate and already answered as indicated by @AnindyaDutta . I do not see any point in so many answers.

Comment: @vinS as long as every answer is different I don't see a problem.

Comment: @GCP - IMHO we can redirect OP to already existing question and try to improve answer there. We should not encourage to ask duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it either with `HashMap` or with `Simple sorting`, as your per comments simple method is as below

```
  int[] array = new int[]{12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87};
                int counter = 0, 
                temp = 0;//variable that holds the temporary value of each element
                Arrays.sort(array);
                temp=array[0];
                int count=1;
                for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++)
                {
                    //System.out.println(array[i]);
                    if(temp==array[i])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(count==1)
                        {
                            count=1;

                        }
                        else{
                        System.out.println(array[i-1]+" "+count);
                        count=1;
                        }
                        temp=array[i];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It still prints all the elements, not only the ones who repeat themselves

Comment: @Alinionut Can you try what I posted below ?

Comment: @LalitVerma the output should only print the numbers that occur more than once, only those, thank you.

Comment: @LalitVerma it works now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.java;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class DuplicatesAndCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87};

    // taking hashmap to accumulate corresponding couter of each number
     HashMap<Integer, Integer> ht = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();                    
     for (Integer newNumber : array) {
        if (ht.get(newNumber) == null) {
            ht.put(newNumber, 1); 
        } else {
            ht.put(newNumber, ht.get(newNumber) + 1);
         }

    }

  System.out.println(ht);
 // now iterate the map
 for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer number = entry.getKey();
    Integer count = entry.getValue();
    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number: " + number + "count: " + count);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution here would be to use a map to count the number of occurrences of each digit.  Then, iterate the map and report any number having a count of two or more.

```
int[] array = new int[]{12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int num : array) {
    Integer count = map.get(num);
    map.put(num, count == null ? 1 : count.intValue() + 1);
}

// now iterate the map
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer num = entry.getKey();
    Integer count = entry.getValue();
    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number: " + num + ", occurs: " + count + " times");
    }
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
 Integer[] arr = {1,2,2,2,1,3,5,4,1};
 Arrays.stream(arr).distinct()
                   .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " appears " + Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), x) + " times."));
```

We remove duplicates from the game so we are left with unique elements, then for each unique element in our stream we print out how many time it appears in original array.

Comment: Hello, i cannot use any methods or classes, only loops and conditional statements, thank you anyway.

Comment: Well fk it, I'll edit my post after breakfast if no one answers.

Comment: @Alinionut but you are using `Arrays.sort()`...

Comment: @Fureeish He probably needs to implement simple sort method himself.

Comment: Yes, sorry, beside from Arrays.sort(), i cannot use any other.

Answer (score 0):

The question has many solutions. I will list a few of them as  a starting point but leave the  coding up to you.

1. Use a `HashMap` and store the `<Number, Frequency>` in the map.
2. If you are not allowed to use maps, you could do a double loop and check for all occurrences. That would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).
3. A slightly better modification would be to sort the array first and then compare the consecutive elements. This would be O(n log n).
4. You could use `Collections.frequency()` but that would operate on a list so convert your data structures (by Streams maybe).

Once you have used any of these methods, you can then filter out the numbers which have a frequency of 1.