# Counting the number of repeats of an element in Arrays - JAVA for Beginners with only the knowledge of loops

Tags: java, arrays

I remember there was an answer out there from 5 years ago but putting the question in context made it difficult for me to understand as a first-year Java learner.

I want to find the number of times an element repeats itself in an array.
For example, 
if I have the array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8};

How do I know if one of the elements are repeated without knowing the array beforehand?

So here goes:

```
public class FindRepeats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8};
        System.out.println(findCount(array));
    }

    public static String findCount(int[] arr) {
    int posIndex = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
            //This for-loop will allow comparison within the array with all other values of the array.
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]) {
                //Because we know the first element (i) will always be the same as the first element (j), we start j at index 1.
                posIndex = i;
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Repeated elements are:\n" + arr[0] + " : " + count;


}
```

}

It doesn't matter if the element is sorted or not. Also, I am looking for a simple way to find the repeats without using dictionaries.

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting repeated elements in an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array)

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without Dictionaries? I am unsure of what it is.

Comment: Will the array always be sorted or do you have to handle unsorted data as well?   Will the repeated entries always occur together?

Comment: I want it to be the numbers of repeats in total. (needs to work for both unsorted and sorted)

Comment: In Geshode's comment, the dictionary is simply a hashtable that reports the number of occurrencies of every number. It's not that complicated.

Comment: Is there any simpler method though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8};
    int[] result= findCount(array);
    for (int i=0; i<result.length; l++)
        System.out.print(result[i]+" ");

    System.out.println();
}

public static int[] findCount(int[] arr) {
     int[] result = new int[arr.length];
     for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
             if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                 result[i]++;
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

The result is: 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1

Answer (score 1):

Let's have fun with the Stream API (please note that I am not fluent in this API so it might not be perfect) :

This will iterate the array, count the occurence an return a `Map`

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(array)
    .boxed() //to work with a `Stream<Integer>`
    .collect( //get a `Map`
        Collectors.groupingBy( //Grouping every value in the `Stream`
            Function.identity(),  
            //HashMap<Integer, Long>::new, //Not needed, `groupingBy` define a method with the same default collection.
            Collectors.counting() //by counting the number of occurrence
        )
    );

map.forEach((o,l) -> { //then iterate the map
        if(l > 1) { //if the counter is bigger than one
            System.out.println(o); //print the value
        }
    });
```

Test with :

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8 } > 1, 3, 7
```

PS : Unfortunatly, I didn't find a cleaner solution to print the result, I can't filter the `Map` like a `List` ... if someone have any idea, I would love to here it. I can always iterate the `Entry` of the `Map` ... but I fell this is overkilling (well the all solution is an overkill ...)

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will output :

```
1=2
3=2
7=2
```

Comment: killing a mosquito with a tank shell, i like that +1.

Comment: @Stavm I totally agree but I am practicing on the subject with this kind of question ;)

Comment: I really like that you used an efficient method "killing a mosquito with the tank!" heh. But I am looking for a clean simple method solution because I do not understand advanced java concepts yet.

Answer (score 0):

This produces a map of occurances:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = 
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

This example produces a set with numbers that occur more than one time.

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8};
List<Integer> list =  new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
list.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i) >1)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Didn't knew `Function.identity` ! And the frequency solution is interesting could you explain a bit the code ? Too bad it required a `Collection` to be used, it look like it would be expensive to use.

Comment: `Function.identity()` means the current variable itself. The `frequency` method returns how many times a certain element occurs in the collection. So compare that to `> 1` and you have your filter. I don't know about it being expensive though..

Comment: In the answer ;) I get the code but it would be more correct with some comments.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    for(int j=i;j<length;j++)
    {
       if(arr[i]==arr[j])
       {
           flag=1;
           id = arr[i];
       }
    }
}
```

This will let you know if there exists any repeated numbers

```
count=0;
if(flag==1)
{
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        if(arr[i]==id)
             count++;
}
```

This here will give you the final count of number of times its repeated.

You can use the same concept with another temp array to check for multiple repeatitons.

This here is the simplest way to solve your issue as you are just beginning with Java.

```
class CountFrequencies 
{

void findCounts(int arr[], int n) 
{
    // Traverse all array elements
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) 
    {
        // If this element is already processed,
        // then nothing to do
        if (arr[i] <= 0) 
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        // Find index corresponding to this element
        // For example, index for 5 is 4
        int elementIndex = arr[i] - 1;

        // If the elementIndex has an element that is not
        // processed yet, then first store that element
        // to arr[i] so that we don't loose anything.
        if (arr[elementIndex] > 0) 
        {
            arr[i] = arr[elementIndex];

            // After storing arr[elementIndex], change it
            // to store initial count of 'arr[i]'
            arr[elementIndex] = -1;
        } 
        else
        {
            // If this is NOT first occurrence of arr[i],
            // then increment its count.
            arr[elementIndex]--;

            // And initialize arr[i] as 0 means the element
            // 'i+1' is not seen so far
            arr[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Below are counts of all elements");
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        System.out.println(j+1 + "->" + Math.abs(arr[j]));
}

// Driver program to test above functions
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    CountFrequencies count = new CountFrequencies();
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 3, 2, 5};
    count.findCounts(arr, arr.length);
}
```

Source : [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-frequencies-elements-array-o1-extra-space-time/)

Comment: What is `id` in your first snippet ? Don't try to get the duplicate value, you will only get the last one.

Comment: `id` is any temp int variable to store the repeating number

Comment: This programs seems to return only the last element from the array. What if I wanted the number of repeats for each element?

Comment: @Pete please refer to the answer again, I have edited it and I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: @PrashantBahuguna Please edit the code. Like the first two portions seem to be very rough and doesn't work.