# Implementation of merge sort to sort array and display any duplicate values from array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I have made the following program and implemented the merge sort where it sorts an array that the user fills and then picks any duplicate values from the array. However, I have a small problem in the main method. Example: I input the number 4 three times and it would display "duplicate: 4" two times; my goal here is to let it display only once, irrelevant of how many duplicates of 4 there are. Thanks guys.

```
 import java.util.*;

`public class Question6` {

   static void mergeSort(int arr1[], int o, int k, int x)  {
    int num1 = k - o + 1;
    int num2 = x - k;

    int temp1[] = new int [num1]; //creation of two temporary arrays to store in
    int temp2[] = new int [num2];


    for (int i=0; i<num1; ++i)   //for loops to copy the data to the temporary arrays
        temp1[i] = arr1[o + i];

    for (int j=0; j<num2; ++j)
        temp2[j] = arr1[k + o + j];





    int i = 0, j = 0; //starting position of temporary arrays


    int s = l; //starting position of the merged two temporary arrays
    while (i < num1 && j < num2)  {

        if (temp1[i] <= temp2[j])  {
            arr1[s] = temp1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else  {
            arr1[s] = temp2[j];
            j++;
        }
        s++;
    }

    //code to copy elements from temp1
    while (i < num1)
    {
        arr1[s] = temp1[i];
        i++;
        s++;
    }

   //code to copy elements from temp2
    while (j < num2)
    {
        arr1[s] = temp2[j];
        j++;
        s++;
    }
}

/
void forSorting(int arr2[], int o, int x) //main method that carries out merge sort
{
    if (o < x)
    {
        // Find the middle point
        int a = (o+x)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        forSorting(arr2, o, a);
        forSorting(arr2, a+1, x);

        // Merge the sorted halves
        mergeSort(arr2, o, a, x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question6 qs = new Question6();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] duplicate = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Please input the numbers to be checked for repetition.");

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        duplicate[x] = sc.nextInt(); //filling array
    }

    int length = duplicate.length;
    qs.forSorting(duplicate, 0, length-1); //calling method forSorting

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicate)); //displays array

    for (int count = 1; count < 10; count++)
    {
        if (duplicate[count] == duplicate[count - 1]) {
            //displays the duplicates
            System.out.println("Duplicate: " + duplicate[count]);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot avoid inserting duplicates as that is the scope of the program, to display any number repeated more than once within the array. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: So use a hasmap, where number is the key and the count is the value. like (4, 2) number 4 being repeated twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array

Comment: Not that familiar with hasmaps or sets in general, that's why I would like to stick with arrays for this case

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go this way:

- If the array has length 1, then there is no duplicate
- If the array has length > 1, then iterate over the elements

  - The first element cannot be a duplicate
  - If the next element (assuming end of array not reached) has the same value as the current one, I have found a duplicate.  Add the duplicate into something Set-like.
  - Continue with the next iteration.
- After the iteration over the array is done, print all elements of the Set-like structure.