# Counting number of duplicates in a given array

Tags: java

Input: 1,4,2,6,7,5,1,2
Output:2

Counting the number of duplicated numbers in a given array for java. I first sorted the array and then counted duplicates. It's showing me error that variable c is not used and that this method should return value of int.

```
public class Duplicates
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]list;
    int[]c;
        int[] c = new int[list.length];
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list; j++) {
                if (list[I] > list[j]) {
                    temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                    c = list;
                }
            }
        }
        int n = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int a = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
            if (c[i] == a) {
                ++n;
                if (n == 1) {
                    ++counter;
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        System.out.print(c[i]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("," + c[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                a = c[i];
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nNumber of Duplicated Numbers in array:" + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It's showing me error that variable c is not used"* -- That's more likely a *warning* not an error.

Comment: Do have a look at this. Something similar is already asked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array]

Comment: Your method is supposed to be returning an `int[]`, but I can't see where you're doing so.

Comment: *"method should return value of int."* - well that's what you promise by the method signature ... to return an array of int values

Comment: should I return it by adding "return list;" at the end?

Comment: And please: use names that means something. "c" means absolutely nothing. And it doesnt help that you use the same pointless 1 char name for the method and then for a variable. Seriously: when you write such unreadable code, it doesn't come as surprise when you later need other people to explain your own code to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's showing me error that variable c is not used

This should be a warning. So the code should still run correctly even with this is showing.

> this method should return value of int

This is a compilation error and since you are not returning any `int` array at the end of the method, your method's return type should be `void`. You should change your method signature as below,

```
public static void c(int[] list)
```

Otherwise you will need to return an `int` array at the end of your method.

**After fixing your code,**

```
public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[]{1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1, 2};
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (list.length - i); ++j) {
                if (list[j - 1] > list[j]) {
                    temp = list[j - 1];
                    list[j - 1] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        int n = 0, counter = 0;
        int previous = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            if (list[i] == previous) {
                ++n;
                if (n == 1) {
                    ++counter;
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        System.out.print(list[i]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(", " + list[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                previous = list[i];
                n = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumber of Duplicated Numbers in array: " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: should I return an int array by writing "return list;" after system.out?

Comment: It would get rid of the error. But since your method is for finding the count, returning that `list` would be meaningless. So you can change your method type to void as I have shown or you can change it to `int` instead of `int[]` and return `counter`

Comment: Thank you, I changed my method type to void. I was trying to run the program on eclipse, but it says "selection should contain a main type"

Comment: Does your class have the main method? `public static void main(String[] args)` And where are you calling this method?

Comment: should I put this instead at the beginning:                          public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[]list;
  int[]c;

Comment: Can you update your code in the question with the main method and where you call the the method you have implemented?

Comment: yes, I just edited it, the error shows duplicated variable c

Comment: Remove this `int[]c;` declaration. You have declared `c` variable twice

Comment: hmm when I remove it, it shows me list has not been initialized

Comment: I have fixed the issues in your code and added it to the answer. Please use that. It's a working version of your code without errors :)