# how to count the duplicate integer using hash map in java

Tags: java, collections

suppose there are an array [1,2,4,5,1,6,1,5,1,7,8,1]
and i want to find the repeated number in array like 1 is repeated  5 time how we can get  using hash map .

Other Question 
 we can find repeated number in array without using key in hash map

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort at all

Comment: Please share some code to show you've at least attempted to solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting repeated elements in an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array)

Comment: [1,2,4,5,1,6,1,5,1,7,8,1]                                                                                        
  this question was asked in the interview that count 1 how many time it appear  by  using hash map

Comment: and when i am using                                                                
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
        hm.put(1, 1); 
        hm.put(2, 2); 
        hm.put(3, 4);                                                                                                                 
        hm.put(4, 5);                                                                                       
        hm.put(5, 1);
        System.out.println("Values of hm" + hm); the told me you are doing wrong

Comment: What do _you_ think you're achieving by using those various put calls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
       Try something like this:


              HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
               for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){

                if(map.containsKey(arr[i])){
                map.put(arr[i],map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
                }

                else{
                  map.put(arr[i], 1);
                }

         }
            // To show the key-value pair ie element (key) and its count (value)    
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry :  map.entrySet()){
                System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " => " + ": " + entry.getValue() );
         }
```