# How to print the maximum key value only?

Tags: java

I'm trying to compress the string by taking an input string with recurring characters.
for example,
Input:aabbbc ---> Output:a2b3c1

I've used hashmap to solve this problem.Taking the same example as above, I'm getting the output as:-a1a2b1b2b3c1

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Integer> a= new HashMap<>();
        String st=s.next();
        char c[]=st.toCharArray();

        for (char x:c){
            if(a.containsKey(x)){
                a.put(x,a.get(x)+1);
            }
            else{
                a.put(x, 1);
            }

            System.out.print(x+""+a.get(x));
        }
    }  
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to print the key with the maximum value only once or is there anything wrong with the logic?

Comment: Just add separate loop for printing, instead of printing while updating

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution step by step is to :

1- change "char" by "Character" in your for-loop

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Integer> a= new HashMap<>();
        String st=s.next();
        char c[]=st.toCharArray();

        for (Character x:c){
            if(a.containsKey(x)){
                a.put(x,a.get(x)+1);
            }
            else{
                a.put(x, 1);
            }

            System.out.print(x+""+a.get(x));
        }
    }  
}
```

2- then, remove the "System.out.println" and do it in a separate loop :

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Integer> a= new HashMap<>();
        String st=s.next();
        char c[]=st.toCharArray();

        for (Character x:c){
            if(a.containsKey(x)){
                a.put(x,a.get(x)+1);
            }
            else{
                a.put(x, 1);
            }

            // System.out.print(x+""+a.get(x));
        }

        // print result here
        for (Character k:a.keySet()){
            System.out.print(k+""+a.get(k));
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: As I'm new to programming, you made it really easy for me to understand .Thanks!

Comment: @JayaKandpal happy to hear that. Do not hesitate to mark it as solution

Answer (score 2):

Loop over all entries and keep track of the max. Also please consider renaming your map to something more descriptive than 'a'

```
int maxFreq = 0;
Character maxFreqChar = null;
for ( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : a.entrySet() ) {
    int value = entry.getValue();
    if (value > maxFreq) {
        maxFreq = value;
        maxFreqChar = entry.getKey();
    }
}
System.out.println(maxFreqChar);
```

Comment: The code was not giving the output as expected and it was showing error when I initialized maxFreqChar as empty.Though It worked out after I made some changes:

Comment: `for ( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : a.entrySet() ) {
    int maxFreq=0;
    int value = entry.getValue();
    char maxFreqChar = entry.getKey();
    if (value > maxFreq) {
        maxFreq = value;
    }
System.out.print(maxFreqChar+""+maxFreq);
    }`                                                                                                               
  I'll try to be more descriptive in future. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @JayaKandpal ah yes, I've made the necessary changes to my answer to allow for an empty maxFreqChar from the start. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Integer> a= new HashMap<>();
        String st=s.next();
        char[] c = st.toCharArray();
        for (Character x:c){
            if(a.putIfAbsent(x, 1) != null) {
                a.put(x, a.get(x) + 1);
            }

        }

        String result = a.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "" + entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```