# What is the most efficient algorithm to find repeated elements in an array in time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(1)?

Tags: java, data-structures

Note-**You can not use Collection or Map**

I have tried this but this is not having complexity O(n)

```
class RepeatElement  
{ 
    void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)  
    { 
        int i, j; 
        System.out.println("Repeated Elements are :"); 
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)  
        { 
            for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)  
            { 
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])  
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        RepeatElement repeat = new RepeatElement(); 
        int arr[] = {4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1}; 
        int arr_size = arr.length; 
        repeat.printRepeating(arr, arr_size); 
    } 
}
```

Is any one having solution for solving,to find a duplicate array without using Collection or Map and using only single for loop

Comment: the key is to use a set. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array

Comment: I have instructed that we can not use collection,and only one for loop will be used

Comment: @pedrohreis I don't think so, because OP is not allowed to use a `Collection` and `Set`s implement `Collection` as far as I know... If you were talking about `Map`s, you would be correct.

Comment: can you make any asumptions on what the array contains?

Comment: @MohammadZubair You say don't use a `Collection`, so use a `Map` instead (which doesn't inherit from `Collection`). You have to track repetitions somehow, right?

Comment: Could you create a hashmap being the element the key and the value the number of repetitions?

Comment: @Legcagy Yes,but if there will be duplicate elements then it will be good ,bcoz we are working on duplicacy

Comment: a very space inefficient way to do so is to create an array of boolean marking if that number was found before or not. For each element in the input, you check if the flag in your array is true; if so the element is repeated, otherwise you mark the position as visited.
However, this really looks like homework, in real life you would use a set approach

Comment: @ThomasTimbul@pedrohreis Sorry,forgotten to mention map,we can not use Map also

Comment: @Mohammad I mean, if you would know the range of that array (for example its the age of people), there is an algorithm

Comment: @Lecagy No we don't know the range ,firstly we have to chck array length,and then duplicate elemnts

Comment: @Lecagy The array is of type `int`, therefore we know the range. From `Integer.MIN_VALUE` up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @pedrohreis [It depends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, but this does not solve the problem as you may have false positives, right? You would need another iteration checking all false positives (yes, it would be a limited number of possibilities, but still another `for`)

Answer (score 4):

If the elements in an array with size `n` are in a range of `0 ~ n-1` ( or `1 ~ n`).

We can try to sort the array by putting `a[i]` to index `i` for every `a[i] != i`, and if we find that there is already an `a[i]` at index `i`, it means that there is another element with value `a[i]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  while (a[i] != i) {
    if (a[i] == a[a[i]]) {
      System.out.print(a[i]);
      break;
    } else {
      int temp = a[i];  // Putting a[i] to index i by swapping them
      a[i] = a[a[i]];
      a[temp] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Since after every swap, one of the elements will be in the right position, so there will be at most n swap operations.

#### Time complexity O(n)

#### Space complexity O(1)

Comment: Almost right. The OP wants to print all repeating elements, so in the case where `a[i] == a[a[i]]`, you'll want to `break` rather than `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have a constant memory requirement for an array of type `int`?
No problem, just let's use a large (but constant) `byte` array:

```
byte[] seen = new byte[536870912];
byte[] dups = new byte[536870912];
for (int i : arr) {
    int idx = i / 8 + 268435456;
    int mask = 1 << (i % 8);
    if ((seen[idx] & mask) != 0) {
        if ((dups[idx] & mask) == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            dups[idx] |= mask;
        }
    } else {
        seen[idx] |= mask;
    }    
}
```

As we only iterate once over the array, we have a time complexity of O(n) (where n is the number of elements in the array).
And because we always use the same amount of space we have a memory complexity of O(1), that is independent of anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution,If there is another way ,i want to know,Without using byte[] seen = new byte[536870912]; this

Comment: You deserve an upVote but i dont have much repotation to vote you

Comment: @Johanes  Its working fine,but why we are taking constant byte array,if the element is large number in billion so what will happen?

Comment: The array is just large enough for all possible `int` values.

Comment: Memory complexity is not O(1).

Comment: @StillFantasy Can you elaborate? On what variable does the memory complexity depend then?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn In your case, the size of the byte array is dependant on the value range of array element. It can't be counted as a constant.

Comment: The minimum and maximum values of an `int` in java are in fact a constant. See [§4.2.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1). We talk about java here, or did I miss something?

Comment: So it depends on the range of `int` in Java. Then it should be O(INT_SIZE) not O(1)

Comment: it's a constant. Please read again how to do Big-O notation, what is asymptotic complexity, and why constants don't matter.

Comment: It's just like if I declare an int vairable `n` and loop for `n` times, time complexity is not O(1) but O(n), even the maximum of `n` is fixed.

Comment: See the last example for constant time on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) for time complexity.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn when the array element occuring more than two times then its giving wrong output,suppose to occur three times ,we are getting this output(2,2)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn from your solution we can get correct value when the element is occuring twice only.

Comment: That's because I store one bit per number. If you don't want duplicates in your duplicate, then we need an other array to store an additional bit: Is it already a duplicate?

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the question that he's talking about an array of size `n` that contains values in the range `1..n` (or perhaps `0..n-1`). Yes, your solution is technically valid in that it uses constant space and constant time. It's also completely impractical in context of the OP's question.

Comment: @JimMischel Maybe I'm not that great reading between the lines. In [a comment OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747966/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-repeated-elements-in-an-array-in-ti/58748363?noredirect=1#comment103785122_58747966) said that they does not know the range. If you have additional information, please edit the question and add those details in.

Answer (score 0):

As these are `int`s, you could use a `BitSet`:

```
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size) {
    BitSet bits = new BitSet();
    BitSet repeated = new BitSet();

    //to deal with negative ints:
    BitSet negativeBits = new BitSet();
    BitSet negativeRepeatedBits = new BitSet();

    for(int i : arr) {
        if(i<0) {
            i = -i; //use the absolute value
            if(negativeBits.get(i)) {
                //this is a repeat
                negativeRepeatedBits.set(i);
            }
            negativeBits.set(i);
        } else {
            if(bits.get(i)) {
                //this is a repeat
                repeated.set(i);
            }
            bits.set(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(
            IntStream.concat(negativeRepeatedBits.stream().map(i -> -i), repeated.stream())
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "Repated Elements are : ", ""))
        );
}
```

Note that (as per comment) negative values need to be treated separately, as otherwise you could be faced with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: While using a BitSet seems to be the right thing to do, it [fails for negative numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#set(int)).

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn for pointing that out. I've edited to work around that pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

Just one for loop, `i` will increment when `j` is at the end of the array, the current `arr[i]` is found earlier of a new duplicate element is found

```
    void printRepeatingSingleLoop(int arr[], int size)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        System.out.println("Repeated Elements are :");
        for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0; i < size; )
        {
            if (k < i ) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[k]) {
                    i++;
                    j = i+1;
                    k = 0;
                } else {
                    k++;
                }
            } else {
                if (j == size) {
                    i++;
                    j = i + 1;
                    k = 0;
                } else {
                    if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                        i++;
                        j = i + 1;
                        k = 0;
                    } else {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: if we are having more than two duplicates,then your code is not working fine