# is there a way to find unique element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an int array in Java (`int[] v`) with differents numbers repeated but only one unique, is there a way to get the unique number with a linear algorithm and only using the input array, primitive auxiliar variables and auxiliar arrays? For example, if I have the next array:

```
int[] v = new int[]{1, 7, 9, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3}
```

I only want to get the numer 9, which is the only one that doesn't repeat.

Comment: @AjeetShah no, if i have this array: {1, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2 , 7, 1, 7}, i want to get the only one that is not repeated (in this cas the number 6).

Comment: The limitations "*primitive auxiliar variables and auxililary array*" seems very artificial. May I ask where they come from?

Comment: The idea is to use bitwise-operator, you can find the solution here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-element-that-appears-once/

Comment: @Turing85 - the whole problem is surely artificial!

Comment: Do all the repeated numbers occur same times i.e. all repeated numbers occur 4 times or 3 times? Also, do we know the maximum number that can appear in the array in any of the input test cases or do we know some range on numbers between which all the numbers appear. There should be some more constraint on either the frequency of the elements of the array or their range. If there is no restriction of any kind then the only thing that can save you is a hash map which has an amortised insertion time complexity of O(1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient algorithm to find repeated elements in an array in time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747966/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-repeated-elements-in-an-array-in-ti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that there's only one 'unique number' and that all the others are repeated exactly twice, then a simple exclusive-or across the array tells you the answer.

```
int n = 0;
for (int u : v)
    n ^= u;
System.out.printf("%d occurs once only%n", n);
```

The wording of your question is not sufficiently crisp to make me sure this is really what you intend.

Comment: YES! thank you, is there an alternative using an auxiliar array instead of going bitwise?

Comment: If the numbers are 'small' then you can make one pass to determine the max number, allocate an array that size, and increment the N'th element for each occurrence of N in the original array.  But that takes two passes through the array (plus zeroing the aux) and is over-complicated for the case of 'exactly one unique number, all others repeated exactly twice' - and it is not practical for the array { 1, 2, 2000000000, 2, 1 }.

Comment: @user15187356 It is also not O(N) because N can be 10 but max = 100000 for instance

Comment: If you mean we do an initial 100000 operations to zero out the aux array, yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is linear, but trades that runtime for space requirement.
It implements a very simple sparse array:

```
    public static void printUniqueElements(int v[]) {
        int[][][][] d = new int[256][][][];

        for(int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
            int value = v[i];
            int b0 = ((byte) value) & 0xFF;
            int b1 = ((byte) (value >>> 8)) & 0xFF;
            int b2 = ((byte) (value >>> 16)) & 0xFF;
            int b3 = ((byte) (value >>> 24)) & 0xff;

            if (d[b0] == null) {
                d[b0] = new int[256][][];
            }
            if (d[b0][b1] == null) {
                d[b0][b1] = new int[256][];
            }
            if (d[b0][b1][b2] == null) {
                d[b0][b1][b2] = new int[256];
            }
            d[b0][b1][b2][b3] = d[b0][b1][b2][b3] + 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
            int value = v[i];
            int b0 = ((byte) value) & 0xFF;
            int b1 = ((byte) (value >>> 8)) & 0xFF;
            int b2 = ((byte) (value >>> 16)) & 0xFF;
            int b3 = ((byte) (value >>> 24)) & 0xff;

            if (d[b0][b1][b2][b3] == 1) {
                System.out.println("Unique: " + value);
            }
        }
    }
```