# Number of repeated values in an integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I need a function or method to find the number of values that repeat in one value. I am not looking for the numbers that repeat, or how many times they repeat, but simply the quantity of numbers that repeat in general. That may sound confusing so here is an example:

```java
int[] anArray = { 
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 3, 1, 
    7, 2, 9, 1
};
```

The number 1 has multiple instances, so does 2 and 3. 
Therefore my output should be "There are 3 cases of consecutive values"

This is what I have so far:

```java
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    int[] array = new int[10];

    do {
      x = input.nextInt();
      array[i] = x;
      i++;
    } while(x!=0);
```

Outside of the loop I need to be able to output the number of repeating values. This is while loop practice, and therefore I am not allowed to use for loops.

Comment: I don't think "consecutive" means what you think it means.

Comment: If you can solve the problem using a `for` loop, you could easily convert it to a `while` loop.

Comment: what happens if you have 3 of a number? Does that still count as 1 case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting repeated elements in an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array)

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Can you tell the range of values which array elements can have?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **must** use *while* loops then you can try the following simple algorithm that makes use of the Arrays.sort function:

```
int getRepeatedElements(int[] array){
    //Sort the numbers in ascending order
    java.util.Arrays.sort(array);

    //Strategy: Store the first occurrence of each number and then move to the next element to see if it is repeated
    int currentElement = array[0];
    int repeatedCount = 0;
    int i = 1;
    boolean alreadyCounted = false;

    while(i < array.length){
        if(currentElement == array[i]){
            //Found a repeated element!
            if(!alreadyCounted){
                repeatedCount++;
                alreadyCounted = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            //New element found
            currentElement = array[i];
            alreadyCounted = false;
        }
        i++; //Move to the next element
    }
    return repeatedCount;
}
```

Comment: Note that this function has the side effect of rearranging the array passed as parameter. If this is undesirable, then you can make a copy of the original array and then pass that copy as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pseudo-code:

- Given an array of numbers
- Group all the values by number
- Filter all values with repetition
- Print all the repeated number

The implementation is bellow:

```
        int[] anArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 9, 1 };
        Arrays.stream(anArray).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue))
            .values().stream().filter(l->l.size()>1)
            .forEach(numbers -> System.out.println(numbers.get(0)));
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] anArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2 };
        java.util.Arrays.sort(anArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArray));
        int countedElement = anArray[0]; // has the checked element
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < anArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (countedElement == anArray[i] && anArray[i] != anArray[i + 1]) {
                count++;
            } else {
                countedElement = anArray[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```