# How do I count the number of times an object appears in an enum?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum Food {
      apples, oranges, grapes};
     }
```

Say I have the following array with items randomly place inside array from the enum above:

```
Food[] arr = {apples, apples, grapes, oranges, apples};
```

Say I want to create a method that calculates the number of times "apples" and "grapes"  appears in the array, how would I go about doing this? Would I use the .equals() method for in item of enum food type? I'm lost...

Comment: You can't have duplicate constants in an enum.

Comment: You cannot have the same constant for enum appear twice, this wont compile.

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the question. I would like to count the number of "apples" and "organes" in a array containing items randomly places there from the enum food.

Comment: I fixed your incorrect case in name of your class. Should be `Food` rather than `food`. Following Java conventions will make your code easier to read, and your Questions more likely to be answered. Also, another convention… As constants, your enum objects should be named in uppercase: `enum Food { APPLES , ORANGES , GRAPES }`

Comment: Duplicate of [*Counting repeated elements in an integer array*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17630727/642706) and [others](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+count+repeats+in+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=osx&ia=web).

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html), an implementation of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) optimized for enum objects.

Use your enum object as the key, and an `Integer` for count as the value of the map: `Map<Food, Integer>`.

```
Map<Food, Integer> counts = new EnumMap<>(food.class);
for (Food f : arr) {
  counts.merge(f, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

...and then you could look up the counts in the map:

```
int numberOfApples = counts.getOrDefault(Food.apples, 0);
```

Comment: We haven't learn anything about EnumMap in class. I'm reviewing practice test so I believe I would have to so something classically like parsing through the array and finding if the item name equals the object in the array than add it to some count variable.

Comment: @JustinJohnson You need to provide such details as being schoolwork assignment *in your Question*, not mentioned after Answers are posted.